# Getting from Livorno Centrale station to Moby ferry

Tags: public-transport, italy, ferries, livorno, sardinia

I am about to book a "Moby Ferries" ferry from Livorno to Olbia (Sardinia).
Ferry departs at 22:00. The FRECCIABIANCA train arrives at 19:44.
Is it manageable to get from the train station to ferry harbour using local public transport?

Is there a direct bus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should be manageable. Take the bus number 1 from the train station to Piazza Grande. From there it is a short walk to the terminal. The price of the bus ticket is 1.20 EUR.  Schedules can be found here: http://www.atl.livorno.it